# .Bat file to add column to CSV and split string

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have date in col D which is date and time stamp. I need to split these into two columns so dates are in D and Time is in E, the data is consistent in the length of the text.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks

First 2 lines are this...

```
vehicleid,name,uniqueid,datestamp,Time,lat,lon,gpsfix,speed,direction,reason,inp‌​uts,icon,gpsrhid,site,streetno,street,city,state,country,postalcode,speedkm,speed‌​type,driver,driverstatus,solidtype1,solidtype2,solidrate,solidspread,prewetrate,p‌​rewetspread,antiicerate,antiicespread,roadtemp,airtemp,pin0,pin1,pin2,pin3,pin4,p‌​in5,pin6,pin7,pin8,pin9,pin10,pin11,pin12
2038240,In-House_Garb_12-C844,,2015-06-03 0:00,9:52:43 AM,45.2342167,-75.7753139,F,68,SE,,1025,cubevan_bw-normal-se-nogsm,2489561661,,,‌​,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: show a line of your csv and your efforts.

Comment: First 2 lines are this...

vehicleid,name,uniqueid,datestamp,Time,lat,lon,gpsfix,speed,direction,reason,inputs,icon,gpsrhid,site,streetno,street,city,state,country,postalcode,speedkm,speedtype,driver,driverstatus,solidtype1,solidtype2,solidrate,solidspread,prewetrate,prewetspread,antiicerate,antiicespread,roadtemp,airtemp,pin0,pin1,pin2,pin3,pin4,pin5,pin6,pin7,pin8,pin9,pin10,pin11,pin12

2038240,In-House_Garb_12-C844,,2015-06-03 0:00,9:52:43 AM,45.2342167,-75.7753139,F,68,SE,,1025,cubevan_bw-normal-se-nogsm,2489561661,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: I don't really have a start to the file, because I have never made one before. I tried looking up existing ones but didn't understand what I was reading enough to modify.

Comment: Can you not just open it in excel and then use text to columns to separate? then you could just use a formula to pull out date and time?

Comment: Yes that's what I have been doing, but there are a lot of files to do so I thought creating a batch file would save loads of time. But I have never done it before and when i search i don't know enough about the syntax to understand what i'm reading.

Comment: so col D is `2015-06-03 0:00`,col E is `9:52:43 AM`. New col D should be `2015-06-03`, new col E should be `00:00` and `09:52:43 AM` keeps unchanged moved to col F ?

Comment: when I look at the structure, it seems more likely, that just ` 00:00` has to be removed. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes you're layout above is correct. and not all the lines are 0:0 so i don't want to remove it I want to keep it as above.


Like this; 
so col D is 2015-06-03 0:00,col E is 9:52:43 AM. New col D should be 2015-06-03, new col E should be 00:00 and 09:52:43 AM keeps unchanged moved to col F

Answer (score 0):

Very simple using [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). JREPL.BAT is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jrepl "(,\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d) (\d?\d:\d\d,)" "$1,$2" /f test.csv /o -
```

The above does a global search and replace for all date/time stamps. A more specific regex could be written to only modify the 4th column.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified a lot of details that may be useful to develop a working Batch file. For example, if the first three columns can *NOT* include a space, and the "date time" parts in column D are *always* separated by a space, then the solution is really simple:

```
@echo off
(for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in (input.csv) do echo %%a,%%b) > output.csv
REM move /Y output.csv input.csv
```